# How to center an element vertically inside another element that is 100% height?

Tags: html, css

I was using this technique http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/gsodI . And it's almost good - but in the second box you can see that the content box sticks out of the outer element.

**How to fix this so that if the inner element is smaller than the outer one, it gets centered, and if it's higher, it 'pushes' the outer element like in this image?**

[image]

Comment: I think that i find solutions. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/center-div-with-dynamic-height/

Comment: instead of saying 'second box' it could be better if you point it with the color of the box like 'red box'. i think you need to vertical-align:center it. and add padding on top and bottom for paddings, if required (like the conntent section). And use margin:0 auto; for center aligning a fixed width, inside a 100% width.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give three major property to align vertically

- Height : ...;
- Display: table-cell;
- vertical-align: middle;

Answer (score 0):

In your second box, change this line:

```
<div class="block" style="height: 200px;">
```

for this one:

```
<div class="block" style="min-height: 200px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

in your css

```
vertical-align:middle
```

Answer (score 0):

[This seems to be what you are describing](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/n2Zg2/). (The second example in the demo)

To fix this add `display:table;` and `width: 100%` to the block (parent) element

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/n2Zg2/5/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="block">    
    <div class="centered">
    </div>   
</div>
```

### CSS

```
/* This parent can be any width and height */
.block {
  text-align: center;
   background: orange;
   display: table; /* added this */
   width: 100%;  /* added this */
}

/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can
   also be of any width and height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
    background: pink;
}
```

If you want to see examples where the block element takes up 100% of the viewport height - then look at this:  [before](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/n2Zg2/2/) ... [after](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/n2Zg2/3/)